# Nancy serving views from module in separate library

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, nancy

I'm new to Nancy and I'm trying to setup a webapp with each module/controller in separate project. Main project is empty ASP.NET project and uses `Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet` nuget package.

What is the elegant way to have this kind of setup?

Say I have the following solution structure:

```
/ModuleA
- ModuleA.csproj
- IndexA.cshtml (Copy to Output Directory = Copy Always)

/MainModule (references ModuleA)
- MainModule.csproj
- Index.cshtml
```

Currently to serve `IndexA` view from `ModuleA` I have to write `View["bin/IndexA"]`, which seems pretty ugly because it will also require prefixing javascript/css in the same manner.

Comment: I've not done this before but try adding to `ResourceViewLocationProvider.RootNamespaces` in your bootstrapper. Something like `ResourceViewLocationProvider.RootNamespaces.Add(typeof(ModuleA).Assembly, "ModuleA");`. You could easily loop over all referenced modules and add them at run time. Don't forget to register the provider (`NancyInternalConfiguration.ViewLocationProvider`)

Comment: Thanks, that sound promising! I'll try it out when I'll have a chance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the nancy conventions in the bootstrapper. Here's the nancy docs: https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/View-location-conventions .

Given this solution structure:

```
/ModuleA
- ModuleA.csproj
- views/IndexA.cshtml (Copy to Output Directory = Copy Always)
- assets/foo.js (Copy to Output Directory = Copy Always)

/MainModule (references ModuleA)
- MainModule.csproj
- Index.cshtml
```

In the `MainModule` bootstrapper:

```
public class Bootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
    protected override void ConfigureConventions(Nancy.Conventions.NancyConventions nancyConventions)
    {
        base.ConfigureConventions(nancyConventions);

        // for views in referenced projects
        nancyConventions.ViewLocationConventions.Add(
            (viewName, model, context) => string.Concat("bin/views/", viewName));

        // for assets in referenced projects         
        nancyConventions.StaticContentsConventions.Add(
            Nancy.Conventions.StaticContentConventionBuilder.AddDirectory("assets", "bin/assets"));
    }
}
```

In `IndexA.cshtml`:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script src="/assets/foo.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

As mentioned by @eth0 in the comments, you can also use views saves as resources but this is outside the scope of my answer. Here is a good article on the topic: http://colinmackay.scot/2013/05/02/configuring-the-nancy-to-use-views-in-a-separate-assembly/